# Qt application link warning: duplicate section xxxxx has different size

Tags: qt

My application links successfully, but I get the following warning:

> d:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   ./debug\moc_yhotkeymap.o: warning: duplicate section
>   `.rdata$_ZTI12YServiceItem[typeinfo for YServiceItem]' has different
>   size

Do I take this warning seriously? If so, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resolved : delete  moc_yhotkeymap.o and moc_yhotkeymap.cpp  file , rebuild application.

reason : class YServiceItem modified ,hotkeymap deponds on it but did not recompiled.

further read (from codeguru) : Warning [duplicate section ... has different size] (http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-427566.html "[Warning] duplicate section ... has different size ")